# use Looper.prepare to display dialog window

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, looper

I want to display a dialog window after execution of a work, AND progress dialog should be displayed untill the work is finished.so i try to use thread in following code.

```
ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(SampActivity.this);
                     dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                     dialog.setProgress(100);
                     dialog.setMax(5000);
                     dialog.show();
                     Thread progressing = new Thread() 
                       {
                         @Override
                         public void run()
                           {
                                try
                                        {
                                           Thread.sleep(5000);
                                           Looper.prepare();
                                         AlertDialog.Builder 

alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SampActivity.this);
                                     alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("finished");
                                     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                     alertDialog.show();

                                     }
               catch (Exception e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SampActivity.this);
                 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Unable to stop SAP.The connection is down.Please retry after sometime.");
                 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                 alertDialog.show();
               }

                       finally
                       {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }

                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    if(dialog.isShowing())
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                       }
                   };       
                 progressing.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY );
                 progressing.start();
```

after running this program the program hangs.i dont know whats wrong in the code.
Please help me to figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update the ui from non-ui thread...You can or use `runOnUiThread` to do the part that updates the ui:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    //display dialog
}
});
```

Or better use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

   private Context context;

   public MyTask(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "msg", true); 
   }

  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       //do something
  }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();  
 }
}
```

Comment: @Nunui tried your advice to show dialog inside the runOnUiThread.But i could not see the progress dialog,but i could see the alertdialog after work is finished.

Comment: Thankyou Nunu.now i got the thing working fine.i just give the work need to be done in thread part and dialog box display in runOnUiThread.